# Can't get Calendar object from Oracle TIMESTAMPTZ column with EclipseLink

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, spring-boot, eclipselink

```
Java 7
Oracle XE (11.2)
Spring Boot 1.3.5
EclipseLink 2.6.3
ojdbc7
```

We have a table in Oracle with a `TIMESTAMP` column. We gained a need to record a timezone, so we switched it to `TIMESTAMPTZ (TIMESTAMP (6) WITH TIME ZONE)`. We also converted the model attribute from `java.util.Date` to `java.util.Calendar`, and applied the `@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)` annotation.

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Calendar timeArrival;
```

All that is from the EclipseLink documentation [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Mapping/Basic_Mappings/Temporal), at the bottom. It looks like it should be fairly seamless.

After making these changes, we cannot access that table (using the JpaRepository.findAll() method for testing). We get this exception:

```
Exception Description: The object [oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ@6b2a085f], of class [class oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ], from mapping [org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DirectToFieldMapping[timeArrival-->TRIP_LEG.TIME_ARRIVAL]] with descriptor [RelationalDescriptor(<my-package>.data.model.TripLeg --> [DatabaseTable(TRIP_LEG)])], could not be converted to [class java.util.Date].
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ConversionException.couldNotBeConverted(ConversionException.java:75) ~[org.eclipse.persistence.core-2.5.0.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.ConversionManager.convertObjectToUtilDate(ConversionManager.java:788) ~[org.eclipse.persistence.core-2.5.0.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.ConversionManager.convertObjectToCalendar(ConversionManager.java:375) ~[org.eclipse.persistence.core-2.5.0.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.ConversionManager.convertObject(ConversionManager.java:112) ~[org.eclipse.persistence.core-2.5.0.jar:na]
```

No matter what we do, that error is happening, despite there being no Date objects in our code anymore. Things we have tried (in various combinations), to no avail:

1) Putting in `@Converter`/`@TypeConverter` annotations to specify the object/db column types

2) Switching from ojdbc7 to ojdbc6

3) Switching to EclipseLink 2.5.0 in case this was a recently developing issue

4) Specifying the `eclipselink.target-database`in application.properties (Oracle11)

5) Deploying to WebLogic to use a JNDI datasource instead of a direct JDBC connection

Comment: Try specifying the eclipselink.target-database with just the basic and Temporal annotations, and show the full exception stacktrace.  You might want to try EclipseLink versions >2.5.0 as the conversionManager in the stack you've shown has changed slightly - I don't know of any issues with 2.5, but doesn't hurt to try.

Comment: @Chris -- thanks for this -- in the course of getting the appropriate stack trace to respond to you, I thought to put my target-database config in my actual Spring config class instead of application.properties, which triggered a new stack trace (unable to find `Oracle11Platform`) which eventually led me to [this page](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Maven) showing I needed the Oracle extensions library from EclipseLink.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sigh. My problem was I had the wrong dependencies.

I originally had:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.4</version>
</dependency>
```

This worked fine for normal usage over a couple of days, until I introduced Oracle's TIMESTAMPTZ into my system. That means I needed the Eclipselink Oracle extensions jar:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.oracle</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Now that I've added that, everything is working again without any extra configuration or annotations. My model field is just:

```
private Calendar timeArrival;
```